Getting Error of PODS while creating new react native project on windows
Im windows user, my previous and existing projects are running smoothly I'm getting this error while craeting new project im also unable to craete/run android file/projects even if i ignore pods
Welcome to React Native 0.75.0!
Learn once, write anywhere
x Downloading template
error Installing pods failed. This doesn't affect project initialization and you can safely proceed.
However, you will need to install pods manually when running ios, follow additional steps in "Run instructions for ios"
section.
Run instructions for Android:
• Have an Android emulator running (quickest way to get started), or a device connected.
⚫ cd "C:\Users\razar\RN Projects\loginscreens" && npx react-native run-android
Run instructions for Windows:
• See https://aka.ms/ReactNativeGuideWindows for the latest up-to-date instructions.

tried chatgpt
uninstalled/installed -g @react-native-community/cli
npm cache clean --force
